# How can I get the max value of this array to print?

Tags: java, arrays, output, max, min

I am practicing with arrays and I just want to print the max value of this array for now but I am not able to figure this out, I have tried looking all over.  Please someone explain.

```
import java.util.*;

class Practice
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] Array = {5, 7, 2, 10};
   }

      public static int getMaxValue(int[] Array)
      {
         int maxValue = Array[0];

         for (int i = 1; i < Array.length; i++)
         {
            if (Array[i] > maxValue) 
            {
                maxValue = Array[i];
            } 
         }
         return maxValue;
      } 
}
```

It compiles without errors, but does not print max value.

Comment: Why do you think it should print anything at all?

Comment: You never appear to call `getMaxValue`, or have it print out anywhere.

Comment: It's working fine ;) ...you just forgot to call `getMaxValue`. Just replace `int[] Array = {5, 7, 2, 10};` for `System.out.printf("%s", getMaxValue(new int[] {5, 7, 2, 10}));`

Comment: Side note: your code to find the max value is incorrect. Arrays start counting at 0, so you are skipping the first value by starting your for loop at 1

Comment: Not really - the first value is read above the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, you just need to print the output of your method:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] Array = {5, 7, 2, 10};
        System.out.println(getMaxValue(Array));
    }

    public static int getMaxValue(int[] Array) {
        int maxValue = Array[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < Array.length; i++) {
            if (Array[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = Array[i];
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the function

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] array = {5, 7, 2, 10};

      // call getMaxValue method and print the returned value
      System.out.println(getMaxValue(array));
   }
```

result :

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply print your console by following way and based java code conventions lowercase for variables in your case array:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] array = {5, 7, 2, 10};
      System.out.println(getMaxValue(array)); 
   }

   public static int getMaxValue(int[] array)
   {
     int maxValue = array[0];

     for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
     {
        if (array[i] > maxValue) 
        {
            maxValue = array[i];
        } 
     }
     return maxValue;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When practicing with arrays, you might want to use Java streams, as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {5, 7, 2, 10};
    Integer max = IntStream.of(array).max().orElseThrow(null);
    System.out.println(max);
}
```